# Tesseract-OCR not recognizing multiple characters in a single image

Tags: python, pycharm, tesseract, python-tesseract

Im a beginner in Tesseract-OCR and I am doing this project in Python to recognize multiple separated characters in one image. I looked up the documentation for PyTesseract and I could not find any reference for detecting multiple characters in different positions.

[image]

I tried changing the configurations but I still cannot detect any characters. My idea is to scan the available characters on the image, print their bounding boxes and find the center of each bounding box, print out the character's rotation in degrees.

Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this is what you mean.

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pytesseract
import imutils

img = cv2.imread("srj8n.png")
cv2.imshow("original", img)

# turn into gray for next processing
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)


thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV * cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
thresh = cv2.bitwise_not(thresh)

# omit the underline
kernel = np.ones((4, 4), np.uint8)
erosion = cv2.erode(thresh, kernel, iterations=1)

# dilate to make the line thicker
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (9, 12))
dilation = cv2.dilate(erosion, kernel, iterations=1)

# find the contour
cntrs = cv2.findContours(dilation, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cntrs = cntrs[0] if len(cntrs) == 2 else cntrs[1]

result = img.copy()
for c in cntrs:
    # for each letter, create red rectangle
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    cv2.rectangle(result, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 0, 255), 2)

    # prepare letter for OCR
    box = thresh[y:y + h - 2, x:x + w]
    box = cv2.bitwise_not(box)
    box = cv2.GaussianBlur(box, (3, 3), 0)

    # retreive the angle. For the meaning of angle, see below
    # https://namkeenman.wordpress.com/2015/12/18/open-cv-determine-angle-of-rotatedrect-minarearect/
    rect = cv2.minAreaRect(c)
    angle = rect[2]

    # put angle below letter
    font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
    bottomLeftCornerOfText = (x, y+h+20)
    fontScale = 0.6
    fontColor = (255, 0, 0)
    lineType = 2
    cv2.putText(result, str(angle), bottomLeftCornerOfText, font, fontScale, fontColor, lineType)

    # do the OCR
    custom_config = r'-l eng --oem 3 --psm 10'
    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(box, config=custom_config)
    print("Detected :" + text + ", angle: " + str(angle))

cv2.imshow("result", result)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: This is actually perfect! If it doesn't hinder you, would you mind writing some explanation in the code? I see you added in the first 12 lines of code of image processing by thresholding the image to black and white, after that I got lost :). I also did not understand how is it boxing every detected letter. The angle of the detected letter only computes it if it is angled to the left, for example here: https://imgur.com/a/rkmM2WS

Thank you!

Comment: I have added comment to explain the code. Hope it helps.