# letter detection in opencv python

Tags: python, ocr

I want to detect the letters in the image of the following detective's answer.[source here](https://brightside.me/wonder-quizzes/13-sherlock-holmes-riddles-that-will-test-how-bright-you-are-670360/).

I answered it with kanren logic code:

```
from kanren import run, eq, conde, var, Relation, facts
from kanren import run, var, fact, Relation

x = var()

murderer = Relation()
# Murder suspects
facts(murderer ,("Mr Ronald", "Jack Green"),
           ("Mr Ronald", "John jacobson"),
           ("Mr Ronald", "June Green"))

sol = run(3,x,murderer("Mr Ronald",x))


findings = Relation()

facts(findings,("First of","January"),
        ("Fourth of","October"),
        ("Fifth of","March"),
        ("Third of","June"))

January = run(1,x,findings ("First of",x))
October = run(1,x,findings("Fourth of",x))
March = run(1,x,findings ("Fifth of",x))
June = run(1,x, findings("Third of",x))

print(January[0][0])
print(October[0][3])
print(March[0][4])
print(June[0][2])
```

So, Kanren's logic answered that the culprit was: John

So when I want to detect letters that match opencv it fails and keeps on failing. I study [here](https://www.thepythoncode.com/article/optical-character-recognition-pytesseract-python) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61224108/tesseract-ocr-not-recognizing-multiple-characters-in-a-single-image).

I want the output to be like [image: this image], and it matches the answer from kanren's logic which is: John

Thank you, any help will be highly appreciated.

original [image: image here]

Comment: all the "kanren" stuff is irrelevant to "detecting letters", which is called Optical Character Recognition (OCR). are you asking to be recommended an OCR library? please take the [tour] and review [ask] and [mre].

Comment: sorry, I didn't know that ocr was included in the tag

Answer (score 1):

[EasyOCR](https://github.com/JaidedAI/EasyOCR) can be a good choice of reading this kind of texts. Its accurate and give you the position of each letter in the text image.

When I tried the code below with your image:

```
import easyocr
reader = easyocr.Reader(['ch_sim','en'])
result = reader.readtext('/ur/img/dir/img.jpg')
print(result)
```

I get the output:

- [([[190, 99], [525, 99], [525, 156], [190, 156]], '**Firstof Jahuary**',
  0.8845715173000117),
- ([[173, 152], [544, 152], [544, 204], [173, 204]], '**Fburthof
  October**', 0.8176276380919366),
- ([[212, 208], [504, 208], [504,
  258], [212, 258]], '**Fifthof March**', 0.7889743493622021),
- ([[224, 264], [494, 264], [494, 314], [224, 314]], '**Thirdof Juhe**',
  0.8849983221023138)]

I can say it is a %95 accurate result.